# Sum with Pythons uncertainties giving a different result than expected

Tags: python, statistics

A friend of mine is evaluating data with Pythons package `uncertainties`. I am her statistics consulter, and I have come up with a weird result in her code.

`sum(array)` and `sqrt(sum(unumpy.std_devs(array)**2))` yield different results, with the second one being the variance method as usually used in engineering.

Now, I know that the variance approach is only suited for when the error is small compared to the partial derivate (because of the Taylor series) which isn't given in this case, but how does `uncertainties` handle this? And how can I reproduce in any way what uncertainties does!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This results due to my `array` being an `AffineScalarFunc` (as opposed to a `Variable`), and thus they not only store the value but also all the variables that the value depends on [[1]](https://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/tech_guide.html#python-classes-for-variables-and-functions-with-uncertainty).

Now, my values are not fully independent (which wasn't clear at all at first sight*), and thus `sum(array)` also considers the off-diagonal elements of my covariance matrix in accordance to [this](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fehlerfortpflanzung#Voneinander_abh.C3.A4ngige_fehlerbehaftete_Gr.C3.B6.C3.9Fen) formula (sorry that the article is in German, but English Wikipedias [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Linear_combinations) isn't as intuitive), whereas `sqrt(sum(unumpy.std_devs(array)**2))` obviously doesn't and just adds up the diagonal elements.

A way to reproduce what uncertainties does is:

```
from uncertainties import covariance_matrix

sum=0
for i in range(0,len(array)):
    for j in range(0,len(array)):
        sum+=covariancematrix(array)[i][j]

print(sqrt(sum))
```

And then `unumpy.std_devs(sum(array))==sqrt(sum)` is `True`.

*Correlation due to the use of data taken from the same interpolation (of measurements) and because the length of a measurement was calculated as the difference of two times (and meassurement were consecutive, so the times are now correlated!)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to square the standard error to make it the variance. This should work and be equal to the error of `sum(array)`:

```
sqrt(sum(unumpy.std_devs(array)**2))
```

Then

```
from uncertainties import unumpy
import random
import math

a = [uc.ufloat(random.random(), random.random()) for _ in range(100)]

sa = unumpy.std_devs(sum(a))    
sb = math.sqrt(sum(unumpy.std_devs(a)**2))

print(sa)
print(sb)
print(sa == sb)
```

Will result with something like

```
5.793714811166615
5.793714811166615
True
```

Comment: My bad! I will correct that right away! That was a typo though, the code actually has a `**2`.

Comment: Then there should be no problem. See my edit to give an explicit example.

Comment: I finally got the code and not only screenshots and found the "error". Your answer was great to help me find it though, as I thought it might be due to certain values which (obviously) wasn't the case.